# Python while loops - What does this code actually do

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to python and I'm just trying to understand this exercise:

```
i=0 
while i<len(seq) :
      j=0 
      while(j<i) :
                print(seq[j:i])
                j = j+1
      i = i+1
```

I've run the code, but I've been having some issues understanding what this piece of code actually does

I understand this is some basic stuff, but I'm just trying a "learn by doing" approach and this one got me stuck

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you tell what is ```seq```

Comment: What part do you have difficulties with?

Comment: This exercice is about slicing.

Comment: Do you know what a while loop does, how slicing/indices work, and how variable assignment works? When you do, you'll probably be able to find out what it does by going over the code line by line and keeping the state of the program in your head.

Answer (score 0):

Code is generating all possible sub-sequences of seq. The first while instruction selects end index of subsequence and second while is selecting beginning index. The beginning index must be lower the second index.

Answer (score 0):

I will try my best to explain it. I have assumed `seq` to be some value.
The line: `while i<len(seq) :` tell python to loop till `i` is greater or equal to `len(seq)` which is the number of characters in the string.

Process -

Inside it:

1. `j` is assigned 0
2. `while (j<i):`, means that loop until `j` is greater than `i`.
3. `print(seq[j:i])` is slicing and indexing: `print(seq[j:i])` prints the characters starting from index `j` to index `i-1`.
4. `j=j+1` means that j is reassigned its original value plus 1.

This will continue until `j<i`. Then, it breaks out of **inner** loop. Then, `i` is reassigned its original value + 1: `i=i+1` and again the process will continue **until** `i` is not less than `len(seq)`

```
seq="Hello"
i=0 
while i<len(seq) :
    j=0 
    while(j<i) :
        print(seq[j:i])
        j = j+1
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
```

I'm sure you understand this part but it's just defining i for the next while loop.

```
while i<len(seq):
```

This part of the code says that as long as i < length of the seq list, it will continue to do this loop. Seq list could also be a string, in this case each symbol will have its own place in the list.

```
j = 0
```

Defining j for the next while loop.

```
while j < i:
```

This loop will run as long as j is smaller than i.

```
print(seq[j:i])
```

Prints everything in the 'seq' list starting from the index j till index i.

```
j = j + 1
i = i + 1
```

Adding 1 to both integers. A lot of python programmers also like to use `j += 1` / `i += 1` for this.